If an integral domain $R$ which is finitely generated over a field $k$ is a field, then every element in $R$ is algebraic over $k$
I am reading Kengi Ueno's Algebraic Geometry I and came across the following lemma (Lemma 1.9): If an integral domain $R$ which is finitely generated over a field $k$ (which need not be algebraically closed) is a field, then every element in $R$ is algebraic over $k$.
I am a little bit confused with the lemma:

Isn't every integral domian which is finitely generated over a field $k$ is a field? Since $R$ is finitely generated as an $k$-algebra, it is in particular a finite dimensional $k$-vector space. Let $a\not= 0 \in R$, and consider the map $\phi:R\rightarrow R, x\mapsto ax$, then $\ker \phi =0$ since $R$ is an integral domain. Now by Rank-Nullity theorem, $\dim R = \dim \ker \phi + \dim \operatorname{im} \phi = 0+\dim \operatorname{im} \phi$, hence $\phi $ is also surjective and there exists $b$ such that $ab=1$ and hence $R$ is a field.

The original proof to the lemma is a bit long and i would like to ask if my proof is correct: let $\alpha \in R$, then $k \subseteq k(\alpha) \subseteq R$. Hence $[k(\alpha):k]\leq [R:k] \leq \infty$ and $\alpha$ is algebraic over $k$.



No, that's not what finitely generated as a $k$-algebra means. For example the polynomial ring $k[x]$ is finitely generated but infinite-dimensional. Your proof does not work at all. This is a real result which requires a real proof and it is truly bizarre for an algebraic geometry text to not name it, it's called Zariski's lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma

@QiaochuYuan Thank you so much for your help!
